# Return props to 404 page

Tags: next.js, vercel

From `getServerSideProps` or from `getStaticProps` is it possible to return the props to send to the 404 page?

From `getServerSideProps` I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
return { notFound: true, props: { foo: true } };
```

Comment: Currently, it's not possible. You can vote the feature here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/28953

Answer (score 1):

`getServerSideProps` is not allowed.
Try `getStaticProps` as the NextJs documentation suggests: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#customizing-the-404-page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).